# I keep getting this error when I do require('/todoController');

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

on my Mac, the file called "todoController.js" is located within Public folder and so is app.js file that is requiring todoController.js. So when I write require('./todoController'); it works perfect and I understand that "./todoController" would be the same as "myRootDirectory/Public/todoController"  because the the JavaScript file requiring that is located in Public directory. BUT, when I write require('/Public/todoController'); instead, it doesn't work even though "/Public/todoController" should be the same as "./todoController". Any reason why?

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Also, wat does it have to do with your mac?

Answer (score 0):

./ Looks in the same directory
Without the DOT it looks for it in the root directory of your file system.

Comment: right... and because the folder "Public" is in my root directory, "./todoController" should be the same as "Public/todoController" if the file that is running it is located in "Public" folder ... which means I shouldn't be getting any error running it... but I keep getting errors.